# How to load JS library in Angular 4's component

Tags: angular

I want to load my external .js file in my component's html because some of my html elements rely on it. But the js is not loaded.

Example of my component js :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
/**
 * Generated class for the MasterSideBar component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html
 * for more info on Angular Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'master-side-bar',
  templateUrl: 'master-side-bar.html'
})
export class MasterSideBar {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello MasterSideBar Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';

  }


}
```

Example of my master-side-bar.html:

```
<script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-mobile">
        <li>
          <button type="button" class="sidebar-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="logo">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="highlight">Flat v3</span> Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
            <img class="profile-img" src="./assets/images/profile.png">
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

When i run my code in brwoser, the js file "/assets/js/app.js" is not loaded.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2797

Comment: I had the same problem. What you can do, is either declare a local variable in your components, or bind your js functions to your window object. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use index.html in project root, and put your *.js file in `<head>` section or elsewhere as usual.